# Android Application Help

Tags: android

Hi I have made a Task Reminder application and it runs. However I am having trouble implementing a widget for said application. This is my application view or main menu.

http://img545.imageshack.us/i/widget1.jpg/

The list you see are just names of tasks that I have saved as a test.

I would like the list to be viewable on the widget and when a user clicks on the widget it takes them to the main application above.

I have read many guides on widgets but I am not sure what to change? I have done the layout and edited the manifest file. It's the widget.java file that I am having trouble with.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this android sample : http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/WeatherListWidget/index.html